# Ошибки в Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Создал пустой консольный проект в Visual Studio на С++, добавил функцию 
include iostream и Visual Studio начала выдавать ошибки [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Слетевшие настройки? Не знает, где искать хедеры?